# App Keys (.plist keys)

Tags: software

Isn't there some wiki or apple documentation which shows which app keys can be used for apple software?

NOTE: I searched the whole net and didn't find any databases on this topic, so if there isn't really such a database maybe we should create one where we can share these keys. Is it possible to create a wikipage in this manner on stackexchange?

Comment: *Added a link but I discovered that the site wasn't usable after all so have deleted it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well-built applications (hopefully including most of Apple's own apps) should be self-documenting -- Apple recommends that developers include a [preference manifest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSXServer/Conceptual/Preference_Manifest_Files/Preface/Preface.html) inside each application that describes the preference keys they use (including their names, data types, descriptions, reasonable default values, etc).

To view an app's manifest, right-click (or control-click) on the app, and select Show Package Contents; then open Contents/Resources, and look for a file or folder named after the app's bundle id with a ".manifest" suffix (e.g. Safari's is in a sub-bundle, so it's actually in Safari.app/Contents/Resources/com.apple.safari.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.apple.safari.manifest).

The manifest file is itself in .plist format, and may be a little hard to ready by hand, but if you look for the name values listed under `<key>pfm_name</key>`, you should find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the answer to your question is "no".

For any given software you can use `defaults read` to get whatever options are set, but if there are default options that are not set, you won't see them.

Blacktree [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) is building a DB of defaults commands (which modify app plists).

Comment: For those who land on this site the command is "defaults read /Library/Preferences/domain.name.ofapplication"

Comment: A littlebit weird that they call these things "secrets" on that Site, but anyway the resource is interesting. Maybe I will later add some of my "secrets" to it ;) Thanx for the link

Comment: seems that I found an other databases where they collect all sort of app keys http://code.google.com/p/manifestdestiny/

Answer (score 1):

[Manifest Destiny](http://code.google.com/p/manifestdestiny/) is a site used to track Manifest (option) files for apps.